# How to insert variable in VBA from another Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I would like to write in my cell a formula like

```
=('[22_07_21_file.xlsm]Daily Report'!$H$59+'[22_07_21_file.xlsm]Daily Report'!$Q$59
```

But I need to be able to substitute "22_07_21_file" with "File", defined as:

```
File = "" & Year & "_" & Month & "_" & Day & "_" & file & ".xlsm"
Range("F32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=('[22_07_21_Tagesreport.xlsm]Daily Report'!R59C8+'[22_07_21_Tagesreport.xlsm]Daily 
Report'!R59C17"
```

......

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=('[File]Daily Report'!R59C8+'[File]Daily Report'!R59C17"
```

Comment: You need to use string concatenation: `"=(['" & File & "]Daily Report'!R59C8+'[" & File & "]Daily Report'!R59C17"`

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to write that formula into a variable first and then assign the variable to the Formula-Property.  If something fails, you can check with the debugging tools the content of the variable.